# Geometry problem given lengths and a median

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have $PQ = 6$, $QR = 7$, and $PR = 9$.  Find the length of the median from $R$ to $\overline{PQ}$.

Should I use law of cosines to solve?

The only problem is how would that help with finding the length of the median.

Comment: So i am assuming $PQR$ is a triangle. Law of cosines is a good start. Make sure you solve for the relevant angles to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the law of cosines can be used in this situation, it is often helpful to use formulas that are proved by the law of cosines to speed up the process.

In this case, and in other problems with cevians, [Stewart's Theorem](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Stewart%27s_Theorem) (usually found in competition math) is quite useful.

Based on the formula shown in the link, and assuming that $x$ is the length of your median, our formula is as follows:

$$3*3*6 + 6*x*x = 7*7*3 + 9*9*3$$

The $3$ is found based on the idea that the median splits the opposite side into two congruent segments.

$$54 + 6x^2 = (49+81)*3$$
$$6x^2 = 336$$
$$x^2 =56$$
$$x = 2\sqrt{14}$$

Answer (score 1):

The length of the median from $R$ to $PQ$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2PR^2+2QR^2-PQ^2}.$$

The proof can be found [here](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml). In your case, this is
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2\cdot 9^2+2\cdot 7^2-6^2}=2\sqrt{14}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The law of cosines will work just fine too. Here is my solution.

[image]

The generalization is pretty straightforward.

\begin{align}
   \cos \angle P &= \dfrac{(2PM)^2+PR^2-QR^2}{2(2PM)(PR)} \\
                 &= \dfrac{4PM^2+PR^2-QR^2}{4 \cdot PM \cdot PR} \\
\hline
   x^2 &= PM^2 + PR^2 - 2 \cdot PM \cdot PR \cdot \cos \angle P \\
       &= PM^2 + PR^2 - 2 \cdot PM \cdot PR \cdot 
          \dfrac{4PM^2+PR^2-QR^2}{4 \cdot PM \cdot PR} \\
       &= PM^2 + PR^2 - 2 PM^2 - \frac 12 PR^2 + \frac 12 QR^2\\
       &= \frac 12(PR^2 + QR^2) - PM^2\\
\hline
   x &= \frac 12 \sqrt{2(PR^2 + QR^2) - PQ^2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Look here[(Polarization identity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity?wprov=sfla1)! You will be easy to calculate the result.